# Rmarkdown / Knitr / Beamer presentation, paginate output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I'm preparing some lecture slides using the rmarkdown / knitr / beamer chain in RStudio. I would like to walk through the output of a `summary(fit)` call, but the output extends off the slide (even if I make the font size very small as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372138/beamer-presentation-rstudio-change-font-size-for-chunk)).

The solution I've come up with is to capture the output of `summary` as a list, then print those outputs I'm interested in consecutively:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE, results='hide'}
summary(fit)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
out <- summary(fit)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
out$call
```
````

Is there a better way?

Comment: What about `allowframebreaks` to break up the summary automatically? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35681531/2706569) scoa explains how to apply this in rmarkdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/). DT interfaces with the DataTable.Js library enabling print HTML widget datatables with pagination.

If you aren't viewing the deck from a browser (PDF or .doc) then you can export the plot and embed it in the document as desired - manually or script.